# Click events being appended on each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with multiple rows and each row has a delete button with a link.  I want to progressively enhance the links to add a bootstrap modal to these buttons.  So what I'm doing is:

1. Grab all the delete button elements on the page.
2. Loop through each button.
3. For each button and change some attributes on the modal based on what button is clicked, including the url that is called when "OK" is cicked.

Everything is working like I want, except that each time the modal is triggered and the "OK" button is clicked the url attached to that gets appended to the previous one.

http://jsfiddle.net/bittersweetryan/9TpX8/  (click the remove button then OK more than once, have your console open)

Here's the code

```
//anonymous function to grab all delete buttons and turn into a modal
(function(){
    var delBtn = $(".delete"),
        $modal = $("#modal-delete");

    if(!$modal.size()){
        $modal = $('<div id="modal-delete" class="modal hide fade"><div class="modal-header"> <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a><h3>Confirm Delete</h3></div><div class="modal-body" id="modal-content"></div><div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" id="okButton" class="btn danger">OK</a> <a href="#" id="cancelButton" class="btn secondary">Cancel</a> </div></div>').appendTo("body");
    }

    delBtn.each(function(){
        var $button = $(this),
            clickHandler,
            href= $button.attr("href");

        if(href){
            clickHandler = function(){
                console.log(href);
                //return window.location=href;
            };
        }
        else{
            clickHandler = $button.click;
        }

        $button.attr("data-toggle","modal").
                attr("data-target","#modal-delete");

        $button.on("click",function(){
            $modal.find("#okButton").on("click",function(){
                clickHandler();
                $modal.modal('hide');
            }).
            end().
            find("#cancelButton").on("click",function(){

                $modal.modal('hide');
            }).
            end().
            find("#modal-content").html($button.attr("title"));
        });
    });

})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You attach another click handler to 'ok' every time you invoke a dialog. Quick fix:

```
$modal.find("#okButton").one("click",function(){
    clickHandler();
    $modal.modal('hide');
})
```

[**Your updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9TpX8/10/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to have to read the api docs on the one function.  Didn't know that existed.

Answer (score 1):

In general, binding handlers with jQuery sticks a new handler in the queue; it doesn't overwrite the existing handler with a new one.

After getting burned by this a number of times, mostly trying to properly bind to dynamically generated controls, I just started sticking

```
.unbind("click")
```

in the queue before setting up onclick bindings.

[Some new fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/CSUa3/)

Comment: Thanks, this is a good option also.  The reason I picked the first one as the answer is because it eliminates a fn call but I'll give you an upvote for a working solution.